# App Store connect. Can’t transfer app because builds are still tnere

Tags: appstore-approval, app-store-connect

Help!
I’ve been trying to transfer an app for a month now to a client and he’s getting angry! The last box in App Store connect about the TestFlight builds won’t grt ticket, and I don’t know what to do. I’ve tried everything. All builds are gone, all info from localizations, I’ve made countless updates, everything. I contacted Apple support but they’ve just kept passing me to different levels of support so far. I don’t know what do to. Is there a way to manually transfer it? Like if I removed mine from sale, and uploaded it on the clients side? And help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for transferring your app to the diff account.

1. All the test flight build has to be deleted manually.
2. All the test details has to be wiped off.
3. All the App information has to be cleaned in the app information section.

But i could see that you didn’t deleted the test flight build properly. thats why you are getting this error. i succeed transferring my 2 application.